# How to negate 'isblank' function

Tags: google-sheets

I want to do "is not blank" in a custom formula. There is a `isblank()` function but I can find neither an `isnotblank()` function nor a way to say not, such as `!` or `==False`.

How can I say **is not blank**?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

I suggest:

```
=not(isblank(A1))
```

which returns TRUE if A1 is populated and FALSE otherwise. Which compares with:

```
=isblank(A1)
```

which returns TRUE if A1 is empty and otherwise FALSE.

Answer (score 14):

The solution is `isblank(cell)=false`

Comment: Nah, too much typing. `ISBLANK(cell)=0`

Comment: @Calculuswhiz only `false` seems to work in conditional formatting with custom formulas

Comment: @BrianLeishman Interesting. I guess `NOT(ISBLANK(...))` would be a bit better for that then.

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to just count how many of your cells in a range are not blank try this:

```
=COUNTA(range)
```

Example: (*assume that it starts from A1 downwards*):

```
---------    
Something 
---------
Something
---------

---------
Something
---------

---------
Something
---------
```

`=COUNTA(A1:A6)` returns `4` since there are two blank cells in there.

Answer (score 5):

```
IF(ISBLANK(B1),,A1/B1)
```

OR

```
NOT(A2)
```